# tikzDevice is not getting sizes right (knitr)

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, r, knitr

I am using OSX, pdflatex, R (cran), tikz/tikzDevice and knitr to create my documents. My problem is that the font sizes of the produced tikZ-file do not match the LaTeX document font sizes.

### Result / Problem

Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image: Screenshot 1]

As you can see, the text is way to big and the points/circles are too small.

### Files

I have a main LaTeX file, called `main.tex`, which contains:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

%% begin.rcode myplot, dev='tikz',  external=FALSE, fig.width=5, fig.height=5
% plot(cars)
%% end.rcode

\hspace*{6.3cm}\color{red} speed

\end{document}
```

I then use a R-Script, called `knit.R` to convert the result of `plot` to tikZ-Code:

```
library(knitr)
render_latex()
knit("/Users/ralfix/Documents/main.tex")
```

It creates a new LaTeX file, called `main-out.tex` which contains the following:

```
...
\input{figure/myplot.tikz}
...
\hspace*{6.3cm}\color{red} speed
...
```

and a new tikZ-file, called `myplot.tikz`:

```
% Created by tikzDevice version 0.6.2-92-0ad2792 on 2013-03-30 18:14:48
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
...
\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  3.00] at (185.47,  6.24) {speed};
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I can remove the `scale=3.0` in the tikz file to get the text right, but then some positioning is broken and the circles stay too small.

### First Idea

If I remove the `[a4paper,12pt]` from my documentclass declaration and re-run my script, I get this much better result:

[image: Screenshot 2]

But if you compare the tikz output with the red LaTeX-output, the text is still too big. The tikz-file says `scale=1.2` for text now.

How and where can I modify something to get every sizing correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just found the solution myself:

Someone can set the point size for tikzDevice manually — With knitr, this is done by adding

```
dev.args=list(pointsize=12)
```

to the chunk options.

Hope this will help someone ;)

Comment: please feel free to mark this as the answer then

Comment: I think the answer below (moved from [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15801683/559676)) should be the real solution.

Comment: @Francesco Please test the development version: https://github.com/yihui/knitr

Comment: It should be noted that, in order to get a *larger* font size, you should use a *small* `pointsize`, and vice-versa. See my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185178/32888) to [Best Practice for nice layout with tikzDevice](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169354/best-practice-for-nice-layout-with-tikzdevice/) for discussion.

Answer (score 7):

Yihui answered the question:

This turns out to be a bug of `tikzDevice` package, which has been [reported long time ago](https://github.com/Sharpie/RTikZDevice/pull/61) (but still not fixed). The problem is the regular expression used to detect the pointsize was wrong (they should have used `pt` instead of `[pt]`):

```
> tikzDevice:::getDocumentPointsize
function (docString) 
{
    psLocation <- regexpr("\\d+[pt]", docString, ignore.case = T, 
        perl = T)
    if (psLocation == -1) {
        return(NA)
    }
    else {
        pointsize <- substr(docString, psLocation, psLocation + 
            attr(psLocation, "match.length") - 2)
        return(as.numeric(pointsize))
    }
}
```

There are a number of ways to fix this problem. The best way is to fix it in `tikzDevice`, of course. Before that happens, you can use this simple trick:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
```

That is, switch `12pt` with `a4paper` so that `12` instead of `4` can be detected.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my real setup, I do not set the font and paper size explicitly. I use my own document class which sets the sizes internally, so the LaTeX parser of `tikzDevice` does not see the font size. So the only solution for me was to set the sizes with `knitr`.