# Fontsize with knitr & tikzDevice

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, r, knitr, tikzdevice

I saw there are already a couple of questions on the argument ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106606/knitr-and-tikzdevice-not-working-together-with-article-options) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106057/tikzdevice-is-not-getting-sizes-right-knitr)) but since they are a few months old and since I can't manage to make the option `dev.args=list(pointsize=5)` works even following the answers I will post it again.

I am trying to decrease the fontsize of my plot labels. But even adding changing the pointsize in the MWE below I can't get the font size change.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
<<dev='tikz', dev.args=list(pointsize=5)>>=
x<-1
plot(x)
@
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has to do with how the scaling factor is calculated by `TikZDevice`. It's explained in my answer to [Best Practice for nice layout with tikzDevice](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169354/best-practice-for-nice-layout-with-tikzdevice), but, in brief, you want to set a large `pointsize` to get a small font, and vice-versa.